# What is the best way to merge 2 tables in 1 (SQL Server), with only one colums in common of datetime type

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best way to merge 2 tables in 1 (SQL Server), with only one colums in common of datetime type

Example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tab1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tab1; 
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tab2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #tab2; 
CREATE TABLE #tab1 (data datetime,valor1 int);
INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES ('2019-01-01',2);
INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES ('2019-01-03',3);
CREATE TABLE #tab2 (data datetime,valor2 int);
INSERT INTO #tab2 VALUES ('2019-01-02',5);
INSERT INTO #tab2 VALUES ('2019-01-03',6);
INSERT INTO #tab2 VALUES ('2019-01-04',7);
```

Output desired:

```
Data        Valor1   Valor2
2019-01-01  2        NUll 
2019-01-02  NULL     5
2019-01-03  3        6
2019-01-04  NULL     7
```

Answer (score 5):

You want `full outer join` :

```
select coalesce(t1.data, t2.data) as data, t1.valor1 , t2.valor2 
from #tab1 t1 full outer join
     #tab2 t2
     on t2.data = t1.data
order by data;
```